# Error with android.support.v4 library

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to use the Android Skype SDK [sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-android-app-sdk-samples) in my project and I'm getting loads of errors saying `android.support.v4 not found`.
The `android-support-v4.jar` file is already in my `libs` folder.
I've followed other articles and tried to remove and add again but no success.   Can anyone help me here please?

My gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def ROOTDIR     = file("..").absolutePath

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "it.moondroid.chatbot"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

    jackOptions {
      //  enabled true
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}



buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
    }

    release {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/MSFTSIG.RSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/MSFTSIG.SF'
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries=false
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

configurations {
    all*. exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*. exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/sanmoku-0.0.5.jar')
compile files('libs/joda-time-2.1.jar')
compile(name: "libucmp", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "platform", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "injector", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "SkypeForBusiness", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "ucmp-enums", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "TelemetryClient2", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "TelemetryService", ext: 'aar')
compile(name: "android-database-sqlcipher", ext: 'aar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

Errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preDexOptionsBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prePackagingOptionsBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAndroidDatabaseSqlcipherLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareInjectorLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLibucmpLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePlatformLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareSkypeForBusinessLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareTelemetryClient2Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareTelemetryServiceLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareUcmpEnumsLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/Users/Anish/Desktop/BTBank/app/src/main/java/it/moondroid/chatbot/ConversationsActivity.java
Error:(26, 8) error: cannot access SupportParentable
class file for android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable not found
Error:(271, 13) error: cannot access DrawerLayout
class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not found
/Users/Anish/Desktop/BTBank/app/src/main/java/it/moondroid/chatbot/ChatAdapter.java
Error:(27, 8) error: cannot access NestedScrollingChild
class file for android.support.v4.view.NestedScrollingChild not found
Error:(27, 55) error: type argument ChatItemPresenter is not within bounds of type-variable VH
where VH is a type-variable:
VH extends ViewHolder declared in class Adapter
Error:(42, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(43, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(44, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(44, 58) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(45, 13) error: package this does not exist
Error:(64, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(70, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(82, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(94, 53) error: package this does not exist
Error:(146, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(154, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(156, 20) error: package this does not exist
/Users/Anish/Desktop/BTBank/app/src/main/java/it/moondroid/chatbot/ChatItemPresenter.java
Error:(20, 8) error: cannot access ScrollingView
class file for android.support.v4.view.ScrollingView not found
Error:(33, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(34, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(35, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(35, 39) error: an enclosing instance that contains ChatItemPresenter.ChatItemPropertyChangeListener is required
Error:(35, 74) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(39, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable this
Error:(47, 56) error: package this does not exist
Error:(57, 52) error: package this does not exist
Error:(62, 60) error: package this does not exist
Error:(72, 16) error: cannot find symbol variable this
/Users/Anish/Desktop/BTBank/app/src/main/java/it/moondroid/chatbot/ChatFragment.java
Error:(98, 37) error: incompatible types: ChatAdapter cannot be converted to Adapter
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.785 secs
Information:29 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: You do not need the jar file. You already have the library. `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'`...There's something else wrong with the code that you should show us.

Comment: Your should probably remove `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'` and fix whatever error you got when you added that a different way

Comment: @cricket_007 - Removed both the jar file and the exclude group line and it worked fine. Thanks a lot. You are a saviour!! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> i'm getting loads of errors saying android.support.v4 not found.

Looks like you excluding compiling it.

```
configurations {
    all*. exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*. exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

Try removing that block.

> The android-support-v4.jar file is already in my libs folder

You don't need a jar file, these lines (yes, all three) each include the support-v4 library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
```

Really, though, you only need the `design` one. You can remove the other two. If you keep them, you have to make the version numbers the same, though.

One more thing - When you have `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`, you do not need to use any lines containing `compile files('libs/blah.jar')` because the first way already grabs *all the jar files*.